# userCanonical validation near label username with FOSUserBundle and Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using Symfony2 and the FOSUserBundle.

If I enter a username or an email address in the registration form, which is already in the database, an error at the top of the registration form is shown.

How do I put the error message to the username/email field?

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation
[Rendering each Field by Hand](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand)

```
{{form_errors(form.username)}}
{{form_errors(form.)}}
```

or create your form theming
[Global Form Theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#global-form-theming)

Comment: The message comes from the validation.xml in the FOSUserBundle:

`<constraint name="FOS\UserBundle\Validator\Unique">
  <option name="property">usernameCanonical</option>
  <option name="message">The username is already used</option>
  <option name="groups">
    <value>Registration</value>
    <value>Profile</value>
  </option>
</constraint>`

But the registration form does not render the usernameCanonical field. So the error message is not bound to any field. 

How can I display this error message at the username field?

Comment: @user1198193 I use {{ form_errors(form) }} and overwrite error message in my UserBundle.

Comment: The problem is, that the message from the FOSUserBundle constraint is a global class error message, and not a property constraint.

Is it possible to configure the contraint or do I have to modify the constraint from a class constraint to a property contraint?

Answer (score 0):

If you set FOSUserBundle as your bundle's parent:

```
// src/Acme/UserBundle/AcmeUserBundle.php

<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Then you can place your own validation.yml file in the config folder, and you can set the errorPath property of the unique constraint like this:

```
#validation.yml:
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User:      # your user entity
constraints:
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: { fields: usernameCanonical, errorPath: username, groups: [CustomRegistration, Default] }
```

Make sure you set errorPath as the actual field's name on your form.